# Node.js module export "pre-load"

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

This is in a mysql.js file:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const config = require('./config.json');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: config.dbhost,
    user: config.dbuser,
    password: config.dbpass,
    database: config.dbname,
});

module.exports = {
    findUser: function(email) {
        const sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ' + mysql.escape(email);

        con.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Connected!');
            con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                return result[0].id;
            });
        });
    },
};
```

then within my index.js file there is this:

```
const mysql = require('./mysql.js');

console.log(mysql.findUser('example@example.test'));
```

When the code is running, it outputs "undefined" and then "Connected!" after the db connection is made. Even though if I do a `console.log` on `result[0].id` it outputs 1, which is the correct id...

**Question:** How can I load the mysql.js file first before the function is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for response cause its an asynchronous function.
Try using callback or promises.
Callback example:

```
mysql.findUser('example@example.test', function(res)){ console.log(res)});

module.exports = {
findUser: function(email, callback) {
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ' + mysql.escape(email);

    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Connected!');
        con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            callback(result[0].id);
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: Did you change the mysql file with the callback too ?

Comment: Yeh apologies, didn't see that change, it works! Thanks